Changing US driving permit to French one, when the test was in an non-agreement state but the ID is from an agreement state
I want to change my US driving permit to a French one, I'm well aware of the documents being requested and the states that have an agreement with the French government that will trade your US licence to a French one.
My question comes here, I passed my US driving test in the state of NY which is not on the list on the state with an agreement with the French government, however, I have a physical ID / driving licence from Massachussetts that I had issued before moving to France.
Has anyone been in this situation and how was it received?
Do they base their decision on the physical ID card or on the original state where you passed the test.

Thanks for the answer! Where it gets tricky is that I got a physical driving licence card from Mass a few months before « immigrating to France » under the French conditions they mention you must have your licence for at least a year for being able to swap it for a French one. the issuance date on my id is fairly recent, and likely to short with the start of my « normal residency « in France. My driving record from Mass only mention my mass licence and recent acquisition. And not my whole driving licences record from ny state. When previously asked the DMV of New York I got my report for over

I'm surprised they don't have an agreement with NY.  I exchanged my Maryland license fine--well--it was still a huge hassle and I had to go back to the préfecture several times before they accepted my paperwork.  You'll probably want your driving records from both the Mass and NY DMVs.

You should be able to exchange your Massachussetts license. The guidance from the ministry mostly deals with the opposite scenario (someone who passed the test in a state that does have an agreement with France and later exchanged it for a license from a state that doesn't) but it clearly and unambiguously states that the only thing that matters is the physical card you present, not where you originally obtained the right to drive (that's in section 2.2.4):

Dans ce cas, il convient de leur rappeler que la procédure d'échange s'applique au permis de conduire national présenté à l’échange et qu’il n’est pas tenu compte de l'origine du droit de conduire.

In practice, French authorities will only ask the US for verification if there is a suspicion that your license may be fake so unless you have to submit a document that states that directly, they may not even notice that you passed the exam in New York.
